# Correlation Matrix from given R output of Factor Analysis

Tags: r, self-study, factor-analysis, correlation-matrix

I carried out a factor analysis of 5 variables using a single factor. How do I estimate the correlation matrix assuming the one factor model holds? The R output is: [image: The r output]

Comment: What correlation matrix are you referring to?

Comment: The question just says 'Give an estimation of the correlation matrix assuming that the one factor model holds.'

Comment: I see; this is a homework assignment. Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: It isn't a homework assignment, it's a practice problem.

Comment: You still need to add the tag & read our policy.

Comment: I added the tags, is that okay?

Comment: As @gung points out, "self-study" includes both homework questions and practice you are doing off your bat - after all, how would someone thousands of miles from you on the internet know which of the two situations applies? - so the tag and policy are still relevant here. It's a good idea to explain your steps if you post an answer, and try to pin-point exactly where you're getting stuck in your question.